# How to parellelize a program

Tags: c, parallel-processing, montecarlo

I am a Physics researcher and i am doing Monte-Carlo simulations about magnetic properties of manganites. I wrote a program in C language and all is going fine except that the time of execution is so huge (maybe 1000 year depending in the size of Markov Chain and the size of the lattice). So I have no solution except that I have to parallelize my program and find a super-calculator. Of course I can't parallelize the whole program because if I do that I will lose the causality of the Markov Chain loop. I can parallelize only one loop inside the Markov Chain and this is sufficient. Here below a portion of my program showing the loop that I have to parellelize. If someone can tell me how to divide this loop into threads?

```
n = 1;

while(n <= Nc)
{
    fscanf(voisins,"%d%d%f%f%f%f",&i,&j,&r[0],&r[1],&r[2],&d);
    V = 0.0;E = 0.0;F = 0.0;

    for(p = 0;p < 3;p++)
    {
        V += (D/pow(d,3.0))*(spin[3*i-3+p]-w[p])*spin[3*j-3+p];
        E += (spin[3*i-3+p]-w[p])*r[p];
        F += spin[3*j-3+p]*r[p];
    }

    G = -3*(D/pow(d,5.0))*E*F;
    dU += (V+G);
    n++;
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to multi thread. (Check out Intel TBB, and OpenMP); Or, do you want to know how you would split this up into smaller chunks to enable you to multi thread it with the library of your choice?

Comment: Your code is very slow as shown. 1. Do you really need fscanf()? I/O is very expensive 2. pow(d, 3.0) -> (d*d*d) 3. pow(d, 5.0) -> (d*d*d*d*d). It is unclear what kind of values are `G` and `dU`. Globals?

Comment: i really nead fscanf to avoid tabs. this file voisins.dat is 6 Go sized. V,G,F,E and dU are doubles and declared inside the main() function. And yes it's very slow especially that this procedure will be repeated millions of times to achieve thermal equilibrium (central limit theorem). I have no choice except parallel computing

Answer (score 3):

It is in general difficult, but Monte Carlo methods are well known to be parallelisable. You could start with a [Pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) but there are many books on parallel programming.

Monte Carlo methods are widely used, e.g. in nuclear physics (for example [Tripoli 4](https://www.oecd-nea.org/tools/abstract/detail/nea-1716)).

You might also read more about [Message Passing Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) (MPI) (and perhaps even [Multi-Agent Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-agent_system) & [Cloud computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing))

Recent [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) & C++14 standards know about [threads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

If you have access to a real supercomputer, you'll probably want to do a mixture of those approaches (so it becomes difficult; if possible get help from experts): e.g. using MPI with multi-threading on each MPI node.

You could perhaps consider vector computing on GPGPUs with e.g. [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/). I'm not sure it fits well for Monte Carlo methods (more for matrix-like computations like finite elements).

[OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) is enabling some limited parallelism with the help of compilers (e.g `#pragma`-s).

Don't forget that there exist a big lot of efficient parallel libraries for Monte Carlo, so also investigate them.

You could also consider a multi-process approach, with traditional [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (perhaps some [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) mechanism, e.g. [Json-RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) if the exchanged data is not big). Then read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and learn more about [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) & [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html), [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html), ...

**[Parallel computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing) is difficult** (you'll need many years to become an expert, which I am not), because the evil is in the details.

PS. Of course you need to use (and become fluent with) Linux on your development laptop or desktop.

Comment: "Parallel computing is difficult (you'll need many years to become an expert, which I am not), because the evil is in the details." All to true... Also Advanced Linux Programming is a really good read.